# Fetch error on Office Script (Does Bearer Authorization token for external calls work in Excel script?)

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, bearer-token, office-scripts

I am trying to run the following script for an external API call with a Bearer Token:

```js
export interface DATOS {
    count: number;
    results: Result[];
    skill_memberships: SkillMemberships;
    meta: Meta;
}
export interface Meta {
    count: number;
    page_count: number;
    page_number: number;
    page_size: number;
}
export interface Result {
    key: string;
    id: string;
}
export interface SkillMemberships {
    "87530265": The87530265;
}
export interface The87530265 {
    level: number;
    max_level: number;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string;
    cached_skill_name: string;
    skill_id: string;
    creator_id: string;
    user_id: string;
    id: string;
}
export interface TESTBASIC {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}

async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): Promise<void>
{
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    console.log("Test2");
    let url = encodeURI('https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/');
    try
    {
        let fetchResult = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {                
                "Access-Token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            redirect: 'follow'
        });
        let json: DATOS = await fetchResult.json();
        console.log(json);
    } catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

But every time I try to run it to show me the result in the console, I always get the following error:

```
{message: "Failed to fetch", name: "TypeError", stack: "TypeError: Failed to fetch at 
self.fetch (https://c0a4c0b1-8f01-4eaa-84f0-6434f1eb8473.officescripts.microsoftusercontent.com/eed0a086-3498-4f91-a377-1e0265ecc0cc/worker.js:99:13) 
at main (blob:https://c0a4c0b1-8f01-4eaa-84f0-6434f1eb8473.officescripts.microsoftusercontent.com/5db7939c-4ae9-4802-8c9f-aed101943d56:183:45) 
at async _____wrapperMain (blob:https://c0a4c0b1-8f01-4eaa-84f0-6434f1eb8473.officescripts.microsoftusercontent.com/5db7939c-4ae9-4802-8c9f-aed101943d56:209:20)"}
```

One of the doubts that I have regarding this script is if Excel Office Script is directly capable of working with this type of tokens, because perhaps if it cannot work with this type of tokens, this type of error will always appear, is this true? ? Or maybe this is due to an error in the text structure or interfaces? Is there a way to do this via Office Script, or would it only be possible to do it via VBA?

Regards

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/external-calls

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem, but with a different type of token. Have you found a way to work around this?

I also tried getting the network details from my browser request, which tells me:

Access to fetch at "{github url}" from origin '{officescripts_url}.officescripts.microsoftusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.